# Android SyncAdapter gets instantiated but onPerformSync never called

Tags: java, android, android-syncadapter

**Solution:**
I forgot to return my SyncAdapterBinder in my Service in the method onBind.

Thank you Selvin for your help!

I'm trying to solve this problem for two days and have read basically every related topic but couldn't find a solution so far.
I have written an Android SyncAdapter and I think everything I wrote is correct. The problem is, my Code in the methodo onPerformSync is never called. In se Account Settings of my phone the SyncAdapter is shown and I can trigger it but nothing happens. It tells me it's syncing for a while and then stops. I do have a working AccountAuthenticator and I do connect my Authority with my Account with:

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, "de.mydomain.myapp.provider",1); ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account,"de.mydomain.myapp.provider",true);
```

Here are some of my Codesnippets:

DatabaseSyncAdapter.java

```
public class DatabaseSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
private final AccountManager am;
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseSyncAdapter";

public DatabaseSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
super(context, autoInitialize);
am = AccountManager.get(context);
Log.d(TAG, "DatabaseSyncAdapter() called with: " + "context = [" + context + "], autoInitialize = [" + autoInitialize + "]");

}

public DatabaseSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSync) {
    super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSync);
    am = AccountManager.get(context);

}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPerformSync() called with: " + "account = [" + account + "], extras = [" + extras + "], authority = [" + authority + "], provider = [" + provider + "], syncResult = [" + syncResult + "]");
    //doing sync stuff
}
```

syncadapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="de.mydomain.myapp.provider"
android:accountType="de.mydomain.myapp.user"
android:userVisible="true"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
android:supportsUploading="true"/>
```

SyncService.java

```
    public class SyncService extends Service{


    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

    private static DatabaseSyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;


    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {

    if (sSyncAdapter == null)

    sSyncAdapter = new DatabaseSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);

    }

    } 

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Entries in Manifest:

```
 <service
    android:name="de.mydomain.myapp.util.SyncService"
    android:exported="true"            >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
        android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
</service>

<provider
    android:name="de.mydomain.myapp.util.StubProvider"
    android:label="SyncLabel"
    android:authorities="de.mydomain.myapp.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:syncable="true" />
```

I also have a StubProvider Class but it's just the StubProvider example from Google. All of this is standard code but when I call ContentResolver.requestSync(...) nothing happens. I don't even get an error and I know, that I have to change my Logcat filter to see all logs. I can see the Log when the DatabaseSyncAdapter is getting instantiated. I did use constants to ensure my authority and my account type are always the same and the requestSync is called with the proper arguments.

Thank you so much for your help, I have just no idea where my problem could be :/

Comment: you forgot to return binder `public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}` Android OS is trying to bind your `SyncService` but it gets null, so cannot call `onPerformSync`

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much! I feel like an Idiot for not seeing that mistake :/ You save my weekend!

Answer (score 0):

It was a very similar problem for me. For anybody else having this problem:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SYNC)) { //Do not do this!!!!
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
} else {
    return null;
}
```

The intent delivered didn't have the action I checked for. It was android.content.SyncAdapter instead.
So removing the if-clause solved the problem.